# URL Rewriting Per User

Tags: url-rewriting

I need to do some URL rewriting but the search results I am getting seem to mostly be related to *appending* query string items and filtering posts based on that. I am trying to add an element to the base URL to be retrieved for the purpose of customizing certain aspects of the site.

I would like to have a URL that is formed like: http://mysitename.com/[my-custom-var]/the-rest-of/the-normal/wordpress/pretty-permalink

In this case my-custom-var is essentially a username and this is mostly a vanity URL, but is also retrieved in order to show a logo, etc. (ie appearance of the link is important, but so is the ability to obtain that variable)

The use case is an agent sending a link to a client and when the client clicks the link that agent's customized layout appears. It should also appear when the agent is logged in and browsing the site.

Nice to have would be the site functioning with no name in that spot, but I can live with creating a "noagent" user for this case.

How would I go about injecting a variable into the beginning of the URL like that? It should perhaps be noted that this is a multisite subdomain install but this only needs to work on one of the sites

edit: Am I approaching this incorrectly? Should I be doing this in .htaccess and just have a rule that takes the first argument and adds it to the end for Wordpress?

Comment: It will be infinitely easier adding something to the end of URLs rather than the beginning.

Comment: You're going to face a lot of ambiguity and ordering issues with such a URL scheme, e.g. is example.com/category/general referring to the category named general, or a page named general by the user category?

Comment: I was thinking it would be assumed that the first section after the baseurl would always be the agent name. If someone needed the no-agent version it would have to be /main/ or something like that.